# jQuery not applying styles after dynamically loading content and using .replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I think this is probably a simple one and I'm missing something obvious, but..

I'm dynamically loading some content using jQuery .ajax():

```
 $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: form_data
    }).done(function (data) {
        var results = $('<div>').html(data).find('#myContainer');
        $('#innerElement').replaceWith(results.find('#innerElement'));
    });
```

That's a slightly simplified version.. The 'innerElement' contains elements styled with breakpoints, and these breakpoint styles aren't being applied once the content has been swapped in.
How do I reinitialise the styles using jQuery (not mobile), I'm using v. 1.11.0

If it helps at all, I'm loading in elements with bootstrap styles, and I have some divs with "visible-lg" etc. that are not getting their styles applied.

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but I think the problem is simply:

```
var results = $('div').html(data).find('#myContainer');
```

in jQuery selectors you must use "pure name of tag" and not complete html tag

Comment: Alas, this doesn't appear to be the issue (my content is all being loaded into the container correctly, it's just not having styles within breakpoints applied). I believe I'm using the $('<div>') selector as it's getting the outer most div on the page (I can't find reference as to why that works now though). This is a legacy bit of code so I confess to not being able to remember fully.

Comment: Without direct testing... is very hard understand what could be. Anyway, I am pretty sure that my suggestion should be implemented, because is the correct syntax, even if not resolutive.

Comment: Ok, it's becuase I'm loading the 'data' into a new $('<div>') element so that jQuery can parse it. I still can't remember how I came across this technique, but that is at least why..